# Microstrategy documents

Tags: microstrategy

Row header locking issue for a Dashboard designing for Chrome and IE.

Dashboard is designed for Chrome but users are interested to see in IE also. Everything looks fine but the right border of the Metrics are moving to right side in IE. Locking the row header fixes the alignment but row height is changing. I'm unable to put the row height that is suitable for both IE and Chrome.

Please check the Attached word.[enter link description here][1]

Comment: please try to rephrase your question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with web pages design, of course with a tool like MicroStrategy you have more limitation that designing your webpage with HTML and CSS (on the other hand MicroStrategy does much more that just creating web pages).

Possible solutions:
- Go for a design without elements that can cause problems, i.e. avoid those borders
- Create a custom CSS plugin to fix the problem in IE

For the CSS customization you can start from [here](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/900/docs/CU_CSS_customizing_CSS.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My admin told its not working out. if you have any other possible solutions please let me know